# Vuex state update is not updating DOM

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I have an array of objects in state

```
  hostInstances :  []
```

And an computed property

```
getHostInstances(){
  return this.$store.state.hostInstances
}
```

which initially show exact number of objects but if I push new object state change is showed in vuedev tools but computed property doesn't change.

I even tried getter via computed property

```
  ...mapGetters(['getHostInstances' ]);
```

and directly in dom

```
v-for="instance in $store.getters.getHostInstances"
```

but it doesn't updated the dom.

Comment: how did you push new objects? through mutations? states must be modified through mutations only.

Comment: @rjcarl Yes, I updated it through mutation and it is clearly visible in vuedev tools that hostInstance getting updated.

Comment: Try my answer below OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need getters as you don't transform your state. You can just fetch it directly from the store using `mapState` of Vuex. You must also modify the state through mutations only if you're not using one.

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

...
computed: {
   ...mapState(['hostInstances'])
},
methods: {
  addHostInstance() {
    this.$store.dispatch('addHostInstanceAction', yourHostInstanceObj);
  }
}
```

and in your store...

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {...}
  actions: {
    addHostInstanceAction({commit}, payload) {
      commit('mutateInstances', payload);
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    mutateInstances(state, payload) {
      state.hostInstances.push(payload);
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Map your `state` to `computed`.

```js
<template>

  <div v-for="instance in hostInstances">{{ instance }}</div>

</template>

<script>

import { mapState } from `vuex`

export default {

  computed: {

      ...mapState(['hostInstances'])

  }


}

</script>
```